# Remove noise words from a pyspark dataframe based on wild card pattern from an another table

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to remove noise words in my dataframe based on noise word pattern in an another table.

```
attributes = ['id', 'text']
values = [
(1, 'Text1 abc'),
(2, 'xyz Text2'),
(3, 'Text3 xyz'),
(4, 'Text41 pqr Text42')
 ]

df_original = spark.createDataFrame(values , attributes)
df_original.show()
```

```
+---+-----------------+
| id|             text|
+---+-----------------+
|  1|        Text1 abc|
|  2|        xyz Text2|
|  3|        Text3 xyz|
|  4|Text41 pqr Text42|
+---+-----------------+
```

```
attributes = ['id', 'pattern']
values = [
 (1, '% abc'),
 (2, 'xyz %'),
 (3, '% pqr %')
  ]

df_remove_words = spark.createDataFrame(values , attributes)
df_remove_words.show()
```

```
+---+-------+
| id|pattern|
+---+-------+
|  1|  % abc|
|  2|  xyz %|
|  3|% pqr %|
+---+-------+
```

expected result:

```
+---+-----------------+
| id|             text|
+---+-----------------+
|  1|            Text1|
|  2|            Text2|
|  3|        Text3 xyz|
|  4|    Text41 Text42|
+---+-----------------+
```

I'm trying to use expr and join columns based on that.

```
df_original.alias("e")\
    .join(
        df_remove_words.alias("r"), 
        on=expr(r"e.text LIKE r.pattern"),
        how="outer"
    )\
     .show()
```

The result I'm getting is

```
+---+-----------------+----+-------+
| id|             text|  id|pattern|
+---+-----------------+----+-------+
|  1|        Text1 abc|   1|  % abc|
|  2|        xyz Text2|   2|  xyz %|
|  3|        Text3 xyz|null|   null|
|  4|Text41 pqr Text42|   3|% pqr %|
+---+-----------------+----+-------+
```

I tried using replace in expr with no success.

Comment: The trouble here is that if multiple patterns match, you will get duplicate rows - which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regexp_replace function but if you want to specify the which part of sentence should be removed such as beginning or ending or middle, you may add some when conditions

```
df_original.alias("e")\
    .join(
        df_remove_words.alias("r"), 
        on=expr(r"e.text LIKE r.pattern"),
        how="outer"
    )\
    .selectExpr("e.id","coalesce(regexp_replace(e.text,regexp_replace(r.pattern,'%',''),''),e.text) AS text")\
    .show()

+---+------------+
| id|        text|
+---+------------+
|  1|       Text1|
|  2|       Text2|
|  3|   Text3 xyz|
|  4|Text41Text42|
+---+------------+
```